# Free cached pages of a process in linux on kill -9 command

Tags: linux, caching, kill

I have a bash script which runs dumpcap for 1 minute, saves the log file and then kills it using -9 switch. But slowly the cache starts increasing:

```
Cpu(s):0.8%us,  0.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.5%id,  0.2%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3934760k total,  3683332k used,   251428k free,    51112k buffers
Swap: 10239996k total,   167380k used, 10072616k free,   **443912k cached**
```

How can I exit the process gracefully so that cache memory is reclaimed and free memory in row of Mem increses? 
PS: Several sources state that free+buffer+cached=available-memory, but I want to reclaim it specifically. Is this possible?

Comment: How is this a wireshark question?

Comment: My apologies. It is not related to wireshark  but caching in linux